# Difference between two exponentiated distributions

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convolution, exponential-distribution

I want to compute the general formula for the difference between two random variables that follow an **Exponentiated** distribution.

It is well known that the difference between two independent random variables, that follow a **Gumbel** distribution, follows a **Logistic** distribution.

It is also well known that the difference between two independent random variables, that follow an **Exponential** distribution, follow a **Laplace** distribution.

More recently, for example, Srivastave, Nadarajah and Kotz (2006) shows that the difference between two independent random variables, that follow an **Exponentiated Exponential** distribution, follow a **Generalized Laplace** distribution.

Gumbel and Exponentiated Exponential are particular cases of Exponentiated Distributions:
$$
F(x,\theta)=G(x)^{\theta}
$$
$$
f(x,\theta)=\theta g(x)G(x)^{\theta-1}
$$
Exponential is a particular case of reversed Exponentiated Distribution: $1-F(x,\theta)=[1-G(x)]^{\theta}$

The particular form of such distributions suggests that there should be a more general formula for the difference between two such variables, but I cannot find it or solve it myself. If I use the convolution formula, for $z=x-y$, I get,
$$
f_z(z)= \int f_x(x)f_y(x-z) dx = \int \theta g(x) G(x)^{\theta -1} \theta g(x-z) G(x-z)^{\theta -1} dx
$$
Maybe with some change of variables this integral can be solved for a general CDF $G(x)$?

Comment: Forgive me -- what's $G(x)$? More generally, can you write down an explicit form for either the CDF or density of your exponentiated distribution? I'm not familiar with one by that name.

Comment: Any cumulative probability distribution (CDF). Exponentiated distributions are defined as taking any CDF and putting an exponent to it.
I want to find a solution for the general case. Specific examples are Gumbel, Frechet, and then Exponentiated Exponential, Exponentiated Gamma, etc.
The CDF of an Exponentiated Exponential would be
$F(x)$ = {1-exp(-ax)}^\theta$

Comment: Ah, and you're trying to do this in the *general* case, with $G$ left alone?

Comment: Yes, the general case